# Opening an excel file & copying sheets using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy a couple of excel sheets ("Y", "X") from one file to the same sheet in another excel file (call it Z - the same file that I'm using the VBA on).
my limitation is that the name and path of the first excel file (with the X,Y) are changing, therefore I'm trying to write something more generic using the "as String" and the Application.GetOpenFilename() command but I'm receiving an error.

Tried to separate into 2 different subs

```
Sub BrowseForFile()
    Dim sFileName As String
    sFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "open the file: " )

    If sFileName = "false" Then Exit Sub
    MsgBox sFileName
    Workbooks.Open (sFileName)
    Workbooks(sFileName).Sheets("X").Activate
    Stop
```

1. Runtime Error 9
2. file doesn't find (1004 I think)

Comment: at first glance force the type of file in `GetOpenFilename` to be ".xls*" and also Dim sFileName as Variant?

Comment: Upon which line is the error being thrown?

Comment: So what you can do is convert the `sFileName` to string. `.GetOpenFilename()` returns type `Variant`, however converting to string you can then manipulate file path and file name.

Answer (score 0):

If the user presses the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button then the `GetOpenFilename` function returns a boolean `False` not a string `"false"` so you need to test for `If sFileName = False Then` and declare it as `Variant`.

If you open a workbook always reference it to a variable so you can use that to access the workbook easily

```
Dim OpenedWb As Workbook
Set OpenedWb = Workbooks.Open(sFileName)
```

Then you can use the variable `Wb` to reference the workbook you opened

```
OpenedWb.Worksheets("X").Activate
```

Note that using `.Select` and `.Activate` is a bad practice and should be avoided ([How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)). Instead use another reference to reference your workbook.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = OpenedWb.Worksheets("X")
```

And access a range like `ws.Range("A1").Value` for example.

---

```
Sub BrowseForFile()
    Dim sFileName As Variant 'needs to be variant because cancel returns a boolean False
    sFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "open the file: " )

    If sFileName = False Then Exit Sub

    MsgBox sFileName

    Dim OpenedWb As Workbook
    Set OpenedWb = Workbooks.Open(sFileName)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = OpenedWb.Worksheets("X")

    MsgBox ws.Range("A1").Value 'output the value of `A1` in worksheet `X` of workbook `sFileName`
End Sub
```

Comment: I think OP uses `.GetOpenFilename` so a user can specify the location of the file, and not have it implicitly defined.

Comment: Actually using a `String` instead of a `Variant` does an implicit `CStr()` on the returned `Variant` from `GetOpenFilename()` but can cause unexpected behaviour when checking for `"false"`, because `CStr(false)` is "False" and not "false"; also different Excel languages might use the local language equivalent for `False`.

Comment: @Peh, yes, sorry I see you have expanded on your original answer :)

Comment: @Nacorid Yes you are correct but I would not want to rely on a implicit string conversion here. Better to use `Variant` and check the correct type, so it returns a `Variant/Boolean` for cancel and a `Variant/String` if a filename was chosen.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thanks. however i need to copy the values in X sheet (which is in a file which the VBA isn't operating) to a different excel file (the ones the VBA is working in). while trying to apply the ws.Range("A1:DU300").Select i couldnt because the sheet isn't really open. the values in Sheet X in the SFileName should be copied to the Temp1 sheet. Thanks!

Comment: recieving the 1004 error "select method of range class failed"

Comment: @EliadHarell Don't `.Select` as I told in my answer. Select is a bad practice you don't need to select to copy something see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Just copy directly without selcting `ws.Range("A1:DU300").Copy`